# What could be causing a file filed attachment not to upload?

Tags: files

I have a content type which has a file field for PDF attachments.

Sometimes a file will refuse to upload and the throbber just spins and spins. The only way out is to reload the page or navigate away. After doing this, the page will often lose it's menu link and need reinstating. The same file will not upload from that location, but others will.

- Usually the attached files will have been created in Microsoft Word and then saved as PDF.
- The page in question also has a link in the main menu.
- Many of the users are based in schools and there often behind a firewall.
- Most users will Windows users

The same file can often be uploaded from a different location (at home say) without problem.

What could be preventing a file uploading from one location but not another?

Upon a failed upload, what causes the menu system to break?

Comment: how large are the PDF that have these problems?

Comment: Not large Chandlers,  and we'll under the maximum file size

Comment: Sorry Chandeep,  predictive text problems